# How to specify infinity or not a number as a value to VHDL real type?

Tags: vhdl

The VHDL real type is basically a floating point number type. I believe it is compliant with the IEEE 754.

In my testbench I need to manually set a real type variable to "infinity" or "not a number" under certain circumstances. Is this possible?

Comment: Real numbers are approximations limited by the undisclosed implementation type which "... conforms either to IEEE Std 754-1985 or to IEEE Std 854-1987; in either case, a minimum representation size of 64 bits is required for this *chosen representation*" for -2008. If you need bit patterns use IEEE package float_pkg. Numeric types have  no bits, they have value ranges.

Comment: could you kindly elaborate on what you mean by "Numeric types have no bits, they have value ranges"?

Comment: Numeric types are all scalar types while composite types have elements. Here the floating point package float_pkg defines defines composite types whose elements are of type std_ulogic and when those element values can be mapped to binary values their composite values can be converted to scalar values (quantities), here the non-discrete scalar type real. Your infinity" or "not a number" binary representations don't fall within the scalar range of values for type real they represent inband signalling for binary representations and not real type values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VHDL-2008 has no `REAL` constants for "not a number" or "infinity". And it does not define `REAL`s to be encoded in any specific format. Implementations might use IEEE 754, though.

> **5.2.5.2 Predefined floating-point types**
>
> The only predefined floating-point type is the type REAL. The range of REAL is host-dependent, but it is guaranteed to be the largest allowed by the chosen representation. It is defined with an ascending range.

VHDL-2008 defines in its annex G.5 the floating point package `IEEE.float_pkg`.

It could be interesting what your specific simulator does, if you convert a `float` NaN/Inf into a `REAL`.

> **G.5.4.3 Conversion functions**
>
> *[...]*
>
> `To_real` Float to REAL. inputs: arg (float). Parameters: check_error: BOOLEAN; denormalize: BOOLEAN.

> **G.5.4.5 Functions returning constants**
>
> For each of the following, parameters are exponent_width and fraction_width, or size_res. The default size is set by the float_exponent_width and float_fraction_width generics.
>
> `zerofp` Returns a floating-point positive zero.
>
> `nanfp` Returns a floating-point signaling NaN.
>
> `qnanfp` Returns a floating-point quiet NaN.
>
> `pos_inffp` Returns a floating-point positive infinity.
>
> `neg_inffp` Returns a floating-point negative infinity.
>
> `neg_zerofp` Returns a floating-point negative zero (which by definition is equal to a floating-point positive zero).

Comment: This answer doesn't address the questions "How to specify infinity or not a number as a value to VHDL real type?" (whose answer is you can't) or "Is this possible?" (a Yes/No question whose answer is No).